# Dynamic android tab activity

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I have created application for taking photos. Application is tab-based. One tab is for camera. It has a layout, let's call it "Camera layout". After user presses "Photo" button from "Camera layout", that same tab should change it's content to "Photo preview" layout. I do it using "setContentView".
The problem is that "setContentView" will change layout for good! Next time user opens "Camera" tab i would like to show him good old "Camera layout". How to do it?

P.S. "Photo preview" has no, and (for specific reasons) can't have any button that will "save the photo and put back old content".

Answer (score 0):

Where is your tab included? Is it using fragments? There are a few approaches you can take:

// If layout ->

A) Have a double layout, being a FrameLayout parent with two children layouts that can be altered between "visible" and "not visible". When your user clicks the button, hide the CameraLayout and show PhotoPreview. Just vice-versa after that to the CameraLayout.

B) Implement your PhotoPreview as a Dialog that shows the preview. It will occupy a large portion of the screen (or the whole screen, depending on your customization) and will not alter the other screen layout.

// If fragment ->

A) Actually recreate your fragment (i am assuming you mean a tabbed fragmented app) when the user goes back to your CameraLayout.

B) Replace your fragment between the two different states of it, switching between CameraLayout and PhotoPreview.